# Magento 2 - move terms and conditions position in checkout

Tags: magento2, terms-and-conditions

By default, when we turn **terms and conditions** on in Magento 2, it's default position is under/ inside each payment method, and it is not shown until customer have clicked on a payment method. I would like to move the **terms and conditions** out from payment methods, and make it viewable when page is loaded. In other words, I would simply like to have the **terms and conditions** displayed same way as it was in Magento 1.9

any ideas?

Comment: I've got the same problem. You can reposition the checkbox in: module-checkout-agreements/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml, but I haven't successfully relocated the checkbox yet. Any input or help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: Let me know if you have fixed this issue. I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Got to Magento 2 backend > Mageplaza (on the left sidebar) > One Step Checkout (Configuration). Under Display Configuration change the "Show Terms and Conditions" value from "In Payment area" to "In Review area". Solved! :)

Comment: is ur issue fixed can you please share full code with me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

at first you need create `checkout_index_index.xml` in your theme, then need disable item **before-place-order** in 314 line:

```
<item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
```

with:

```
<item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

Read more here [Magento Custimize Checkout Step](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html)

Then you need **re-add** that element on the end of your Checkout, after place order button, like this:

```
<item name="after-place-agreements" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/payment/before-place-order</item>
    </item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="agreementss" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Then copy in your default template(html) after place order:

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after-place-agreements') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```

Good luck!! :)

[See More here](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/dont-mess-magento-2-checkout/)

Comment: I try your answer. It's working proper. But, validation is not working. So, can you please give me code for validation of terms and conditions?

Comment: Hi Matej. I've managed to put the terms and conditions out of the payment section into the sidebar. But the validation of the terms and conditions checkbox is not working. Do you know why?

Comment: can please share code of same as its not working for me!

Comment: Hello. How can I add same in Shipping methods step?

Answer (score 4):

If someone wonder how to make validation of agreements work after moving it (for example to afterMethods area) then you have to change one line in

*js/model/agreement-validator.js*

`agreementsInputPath = '.payment-method._active div.checkout-agreements input';`

to proper value depending on where you will have now the inputs of checkout-agreements

Comment: The missing piece, thanks.