# Validation of the terms and conditions (custom module)

Tags: magento2, module, checkout, magento2.2.3, terms-and-conditions

I've made a custom module which enables me to have the T&C checkbox moved beneath the payment methods and the place order button inside the summary div, like so:

[image: Checkout view]

Now, whenever I select a payment method, check the box from the Terms and Conditions and press 'Place Order', the following pops up:

[image: Error message]

I've tried the following, but unfortunately no luck:

[Magento 2 - move terms and conditions position in checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160056/magento-2-move-terms-and-conditions-position-in-checkout)

The Ajax payload after submitting order:

[image]

When using the checkout without the module, the content of the payload (payment-information) has:

```
extension_attributes: {agreement_ids: ["1"]}
agreement_ids: ["1"]
```

While when using my custom module, it's as follows:

```
extension_attributes: {agreement_ids: [""]}
agreement_ids: [""]
```

Thus it's empty... this probably seems to be the problem. How do I fix this?

#### CODE

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Checkout" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Checkout::css/checkout.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>


        <!-- Disabling the T&C checkbox under payment methods -->
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="before-place-order" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <!-- Moving terms and conditions after payment methods -->
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="agreements" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="agreements-validator" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/agreement-validation</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <!-- Moving place order button to sidebar -->
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/js/view/payment</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Checkout/button</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>



    </body>
</page>
```

web/template/button.html

```
<!-- ko if: (isVisible()) -->
<div class="actions-toolbar-trigger" id="place-order-trigger-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="button action primary" id="place-order-trigger" value="Place Order" >
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'">Place Order</span>
    </button>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

web/js/view/payment.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        ko,
        Component,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';
        console.log('Running');
        return Component.extend({

            isVisible: function () {
                return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
            },
            initialize: function () {
                $(function() {
                    $('body').on("click", '#place-order-trigger', function () {

                        // Parse JSON here somehow?
                        $(".payment-method._active").find('.action.primary.checkout').trigger( 'click' );

                    });
                });
                var self = this;
                this._super();
            }

        });


    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after being absent for a while I've found what causes the agreements to not be validated.

There is this file called `agreements-assigner.js`, located in

> Module_CheckoutAgreements/view/frontend/web/js/model

In this file, there is a variable called `agreementForm`. This variable is assigned to the checkbox of the terms and agreements. Originally like this:

```
agreementForm = $('.payment-method._active div[data-role=checkout-agreements] input');
```

But of course, I moved the checkbox out of it's original location, so this path to the checkbox does not exist anymore.

If you, for example, change the variable as follows:

```
agreementForm = $('div[data-role=checkout-agreements] input');
```

The .js-file is able to locate your checkout agreements checkbox! Now your order can be placed succesfully.

A rather simple fix. I was trying to fix it using custom .js and stuff, and totally oversaw this file... ;)

***NOTE:*** do not edit the core file directly. Rather copy it to your module or theme and alter the file according to your needs.

Comment: @Bran, Can you please tell me version ?

Answer (score 0):

add following line   in your custom module

> app/code/Magento/CheckoutAgreements/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout-agreements.js   line no- 48 to 77

```
 /**
         * build a unique id for the term checkbox
         *
         * @param {Object} context - the ko context
         * @param {Number} agreementId
         */
        getCheckboxId: function (context, agreementId) {
            var paymentMethodName = '',
                paymentMethodRenderer = context.$parents[1];

            // corresponding payment method fetched from parent context
            if (paymentMethodRenderer) {
                // item looks like this: {title: "Check / Money order", method: "checkmo"}
                paymentMethodName = paymentMethodRenderer.item ?
                  paymentMethodRenderer.item.method : '';
            }

            return 'agreement_' + paymentMethodName + '_' + agreementId;
        },

        /**
         * Init modal window for rendered element
         *
         * @param {Object} element
         */
        initModal: function (element) {
            agreementsModal.createModal(element);
        }
    });
});
```

> change in file Magento/CheckoutAgreements/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html

Replace
`'id': 'agreement_' + agreementId,`
in line 14

with

```
 'id': $parent.getCheckboxId($parentContext, agreementId),
```

Replace

> `<label data-bind="attr: {'for': 'agreement_' + agreementId}">`

with

> `<label data-bind="attr: {'for': $parent.getCheckboxId($parentContext,
>   agreementId)}">`

in **line 18**

**Reference**: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/14b9b9813c9a16c0c45505885503cfb71bc4eb8d

Comment: I already use the latest version of Magento 2 (2.2.3). In this version, all the code is already as you mentioned. Is it of any use for you if I'd share my code in my answer?

Comment: hi @lalit mohan, i am using default magento 2.2.4, getting same error once i clicked place order button. can you please explain in detail with the answer